# Mysql LIKE 2nd character and 2nd last character both are 'm'

Tags: mysql, regex

I try to find query to find a string that 2nd character and 2nd last character both are letter m.

```
SELECT last_name
FROM employees
WHERE (last_name LIKE '_m%m_' AND LENGTH(last_name) >= '3');
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you need a regex or do you use  mysql like function? If you have tried something, post it and describe what problem you have

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I think i need the sql query where condition. one second i will post something here.

Comment: @JvdV  not sure if I understand your point well. Why or in this case will help? since I need to check the length before matching the regex, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `OR` instead of `AND`? I don't see the point of `AND` when your `LIKE` operator allready rules out names below three characters. You don't need to use regex nor a check for length:

```
SELECT last_name FROM employees
    WHERE last_name LIKE '_m_'
       OR last_name LIKE '_m%m_';
```

The use of `OR` and `LIKE` does catch any string that has *at least 3 characters*.

---

If you must use regex, try `REGEXP` operator:

```
SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE last_name REGEXP '^.m(.*m)?.$';
```

Where the pattern means:

- `^.m` - Start-line anchor with a single character and a literal 'm';
- `(.*m)?` - Optional capture group to match 0+ characters upto a literal 'm';
- `.$` - A single character with end-line anchor.

The benefit of `REGEXP` is that it's a bit less verbose if you need case-insensitive matching using pattern: `'^.[Mm](.*[Mm])?.$'`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VlM8eI/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you need all record with second and last character is *m* you can use the following query:

```
select * from <table> where <column> like '_m%m'
```

the `_` in the query is a placeholder for one character and `%` for many characters

Comment: SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE first_name LIKE '_m%m_'; is "%" same as ".*" will match 0 or more in mysql regex?  How about the case "Hmh"? should I check the length of string need to greater than 3?

Comment: @pavqoma is this what you have tried? Than add it to your question not as comment to my answer